# Targeting Nuget Packages Per Project In A Solution

Tags: architecture, projects-and-solutions, nuget

I have 1 solution with six projects:

1. **Client**
2. **Client.Test**
3. **Domain**
4. **Domain.Test**
5. **Common**
6. **Common.Test**

As you can see, I have 3 projects which are used to house tests. I would like to install xUnit, via NuGet, these three packages but not add this package to the three non testing projects. What would be the easiest way to manage dependencies of this nature?

As an aside I would also like to add different projects (Like Ninject) in a similar manner to the Client and Domain. I thought it might be useful to mention this for the purposes of adding more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found The Answer [Here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog). You need to select the Solution Name and install the packages from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following command in the nuget console:

```
PM> Install-Package [InsertNewPackageNameHere] -Version 1.0.0 -Project [MyMvcApplication1]
```

(where '*InsertNewPackageNameHere*' can be any package name i.e. EntityFrameWork and '*MyMvcApplication*' can be the name of any project in your solution)

(to find the nuget console in vs2012 menu click: Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console)